# how to split string where string length >120 in c#

Tags: c#

How to split string in C#.
I write a code but find some error like Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
my code is

```
DataTable dt1 = ((DataTable)ViewState["tblsms"]);



    string smstxt = Convert.ToString(((TextBox)SMSGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtsms")).Text.Trim());
    int smstext = smstxt.Length;
    int j = 0;
    int z= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < smstext; i++)
    {
        string smstxt1 = string.Empty;

        if (smstext >= 120)
        {
            z = z +120;
        }
        else
        {
            z = smstext;
        }
        smstxt1 = smstxt.Substring(j,z).ToString();
        j = j + 120;


        string title = Convert.ToString(((TextBox)SMSGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTitl")).Text.Trim());
        string recptelno = Convert.ToString(((TextBox)SMSGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTelno")).Text.Trim());
        string snid = Convert.ToString(((Label)SMSGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblsnid")).Text.Trim());
        if (snid == "")
        {
            snid = "00";
        }
        DataSet ds2 = (DataSet)Session["dsLogIn1"];
        string postedbyid = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["usrid"].ToString();
        string posttrmid = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TermID"].ToString();
        string postseson = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SessionID"].ToString();


        int ck1 = 0;

        bool _result1 = Proc1.UpdateRecords("", "SP_ENTRY_SMS", "UPDATESMS", snid, title, smstxt1, recptelno, ck1.ToString(), postedbyid, posttrmid, postseson, "false", "false");

        if (!_result1)
        {

            this.lblwkMsg.Text = "Message Not Save";
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            this.lblwkMsg.Text = "Message Save Successfully";

        }

        i = i + 120;

        dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["sdescription"] = title;
        dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["smstext"] = smstxt1;
        dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["recptelno"] = recptelno;
        dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["reqflg"] = ck1;
        //dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["postedbyid"] = postedbyid;
        //dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["posttrmid"] = posttrmid;
        //dt1.Rows[e.RowIndex]["postseson"] = postseson;
        this.SMSGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        ViewState["tblsms"] = dt1;
        this.condition();
        this.SMSGridView.DataSource = ViewState["tblsms"];
        this.SMSGridView.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: Don't Post your full code Specify only that area of code where you getting errors

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with something like this:

```cs
const int len = 120;
int i = 0;
var strings = new List<string>();

while ( str.Length > (i + len) )
{
    strings.Add(str.Substring(i, len);
    i += len;
}

strings.Add(str.Substring(i));
```